# Android: Using button from a non-acitvity class in activity class

Tags: android, class, button, android-activity

I am wondering if it is possible to access a button from a non-activity class using an activity class? The button is in a different xml file than the one of the activity class.

Also, is it possible to create options menu in the non-activity class?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do something going against the framework of Android, for whatever reason. Probably your real problem is something different, so perhaps try to explain WHY you are trying to do this

Comment: Do you want both buttons to have the exact same look/style by any chance?

Comment: Yes I want them to  be the same

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to access any UI element from a non-activity class, you need to pass the context to your class. A rough method is:

in your activity's onCreate() method:

```
myInstance.setContext(this);
```

and in your Class, you have:

```
Context mContext;

public void setContext(Context c){
mContext = c;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if it is possible to access a button from a
>   non-activity class using an activity class?

Yes, it's possible if the non-activity class can access the methods of an activity class. This can be done by passing the reference of an activity to that non-activity class in the `onCreate()` method. But remember to release that reference and any other reference to the activity Views when the Activity is destroyed, that is when it's onDestroy() method being called.

> The button is in a different xml file than the one of the activity
>   class.

A button that is not added to an Activity's View Tree can be accessed. You can inflate the layout that contains the button and add the inflated View root to your Activity's `ViewGroup`.

> Also, is it possible to create options menu in the non-activity class?

Yes, it's possible if the non-activity class can access the methods of an activity class.

Comment: How would you go about accessing the button? So when inflating the menu do you call the view that the button is in? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Access the button or create options menu, what do you want?

Comment: Which one would be the easier method?

Comment: I'm not sure. So you are trying to solve a problem in your app? Why don't your show the problem.

Comment: I am curious if it's possible and if so what way would be best

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can correct me if I'm wrong. But my assumption answer to your question and how I understand what you trying to achieve. Android has made it easy to access controls in other xml files. You have the < include> which you can include other non-activity(fragments) in your activity. Actually it's pretty easy to do this that is the first way to do it. I know they is another way still playing around with your xml files. There is resource to bring non-activity controls to activity layouts with having to do much programmatically. Look at resources available to you on your layout builder.